# Validation not working on Laravel version 10

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my `register` method in my `AuthController`,

```
 public function register(Request $request)
 {
    $request->validate([
            'firstName' => 'required | string',
            'lastName' => 'required | string',
            'email'    => 'required | email | unique:users,email',
        ], [
            'email.unique' => 'User with this email already exists',
        ]);
 }
```

I'm using `postman` to send the `API` requests,

This is the API endpoint present in my `routes.php`,

```
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

However, when I send the `POST` request to this endpoint using `postman` some HTML content with a `200` response code returns back even though the fields are set to empty when sending. When I click the preview tab in postman it shows me Laravel home page.

Comment: if this is in routes.php then when you post through postman before this validation, csrf-token also need to be present else it will redirect back. which is not available in case of postman and you will see the home page as the redirected page.

Comment: Try adding header `Accept: application/json` to get the response in json format.

Comment: Also I suggest that the apis must defined in api.php in routes folder to remove session related validation on the api calls

Comment: add Accept: application/json to your request headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is in `routes.php` then when you post through postman before this validation, `csrf-token` also need to be present else it will redirect back. which is not available in case of postman and you will see the home page as the redirected page.

Try adding header `Accept: application/json` to get the response in json format.

Also I suggest that the apis must defined in api.php in routes folder to remove session related validation on the api calls

so define your routes in `api.php` like

```
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

then call it through post as

`http://localhost/project/api/register`